# Laravel get profile name

Tags: php, laravel

I'm laravel newbie and I'm making simple CMS. So i have simple question:
[image: CMS]

I wan't when click on avatar - redirect to user profile (http://example.com/profiles/nickname/id)
In DB it saves that:
[image: DB]

as you see author_id I have, now I need to get author name from `users` table:
[image: users table]

And then generate url: http://example.com/profiles/Evaldas/2 (Evaldas, because `author_id` is `2` in `topics table`)

My routes file:

`Route::get('topic/{tname}/{tid}', 'viewTopic@showTopic');`

My `viewTopic.php` Controller:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use DB;
use View;

class viewTopic extends Controller 
{
    public function showTopic($tname, $tid)
    {
        return View::make('posts', [
            'topics'  => DB::table('topics')
                ->where('id', $tid)
                ->where('seo_title', $tname)
                ->first(),
            'posts'  => DB::table('posts')
                ->where('topic_id', $tid)
                ->select()
                ->get()
        ]);
    }
}
```

And layout:

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('content')
<div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="HERE MUST BE HREF TO PROFILE">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://localhost/uploads/avatars/2.jpg" style="width: 64px">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body" rel="#author{{ $topics->author_id }}">
    <h4 class="media-heading">{{ $topics->title }}</h4>
    @if(!empty($topics->text))
    {{ $topics->text }}
    @else
    Message empty :(
    @endif
  </div>
    @foreach($posts as $post)
    <div class="media">
  <div class="media-left">
    <a href="HERE MUST BE HREF TO PROFILE">
      <img class="media-object" src="http://localhost/uploads/avatars/1.png" style="width: 64px">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body" rel="#post{{ $post->pid }}">
  {{ $post->text }}
  </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
@stop
```

Thanks so much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the Query Builder, you can use the join() method:

```
DB::table('posts')
->where('topic_id', $tid)
->join('users', 'user.id', '=', 'posts.author_id')
->select()
->get()
```

This way, the user information will be available:

```
 $post->nickname
```

You can then build your URL using a laravel helper, for exemple, if you have a profile route:

```
<a href="{{route('profile', ['nickname' => $post->nickname, 'id' => $post->author_id]);}}">
```

An other method is to create models for your tables and define relationship between them.

See this: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

Using this method, you will be able to write things like `$post->author->nickname`

Comment: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `topics` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `topics`.`author_id` where `id` = 14)` and `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous`

Comment: maybe you can try write relationship code? :( I'm newbie I can't :(